# AWS SES Receipt Rule not trigger

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have verified 2 emails and 1 domain

I created lambda function for testing and trigger on incoming email

I set receipt Rule for incoming Emails on SES and set trigger to my lambda function

I tried to send an email to the verified email to trigger lambda function

But itsn't trigger my lambda function

Do i need to set anythingelse to work this?

Comment: Any chance you figured this out?  Sorry I can't be any help